# Is it right way to use Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory library with AAD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, owin.security

We have two Application registered in the same AAD **B2C** tenant via "New" and "Old" portal.

Authentication with "Old" Application credentials works correct. 
With "New" Application credentials - error appears:

*IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve SecurityKeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
    (
    IsReadOnly = False,
    Count = 1,
    Clause[0] = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.NamedKeySecurityKeyIdentifierClause
    )
'*

Is it right way to use Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirector library (to protect ASP.Net Web API) with Application registered in AAD **B2C** tenant.

P.S. My question is based on this [post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_azure_simplified/2015/03/22/getting-started-using-azure-active-directory-aad-for-authenticating-automated-clients-c/#comment-15).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should only create applications via the Azure AD B2C blade in the [new Azure portal (portal.azure.com)](https://portal.azure.com).**

Do NOT create applications for Azure AD B2C using the classic Azure Portal (manage.windowsazure.com).

**If you want to secure a WebApp, you should use Owin's OpenIdConnectAuthentication**. This document has more details on how to do this: [Sign-Up & Sign-In in a ASP.NET Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi)

**If you want to secure a WebAPI, you should use Owin's OAuthBearerAuthentication**. This document has more details on how to do this: [Build a .NET web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-api-dotnet)

---

Samples configuration of a WebApp:

```cs
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // Generate the metadata address using the tenant and policy information
            MetadataAddress = String.Format(AadInstance, Tenant, DefaultPolicy),

            // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
            ClientId = ClientId,
            RedirectUri = RedirectUri,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = RedirectUri,

            // Specify the callbacks for each type of notifications
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
            },

            // Specify the claims to validate
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name"
            },

            // Specify the scope by appending all of the scopes requested into one string (separated by a blank space)
            Scope = $"{OpenIdConnectScopes.OpenId} {YourScope1} {YourScope2}"
        }
    );
}
```

---

Samples configuration of a Web API:

```cs
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        TokenValidationParameters tvps = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            // Accept only those tokens where the audience of the token is equal to the client ID of this app
            ValidAudience = ClientId,
            AuthenticationType = Startup.DefaultPolicy
        };

        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // This SecurityTokenProvider fetches the Azure AD B2C metadata & signing keys from the OpenIDConnect metadata endpoint
            AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(tvps, new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider(String.Format(AadInstance, Tenant, DefaultPolicy)))
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Hey @user1776813, can you please flag this question as answered?